# How can I use Webpack import with variables in the string?

Tags: webpack

Hey anybody know the answer to this webpack riddle? Line 97 will work where the app_name is static and the package name is a var but when I have two vars in the string it wont work.

https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2Q193W0m2U3B1a1D2A3m/Image%202018-08-07%20at%2012.30.58%20PM.png

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give a proper [mcve], **in text form**. Pictures of code are useless, and *"wont work"* doesn't give much info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with dynamic imports.

There's a nice article regarding it:
https://oprea.rocks/blog/es6-dynamic-import-and-webpack-memory-leaks/

Then you also have an open issue on webpack's github page:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4292#issuecomment-280165950

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks so much David. Going to give this a shot.